# How to show Flutter firebase realtime database on widgets with data updates using Stream builder?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase for first time. My app is connected to firebase successfully and i am able access data on screen by following code. My problem is that while Values changes in database it should be changed on the screen without any button press or something.

```
stream:  FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("app3-e0228-default-rtdb").onvalue,
```

while i use above line the data on the screen will not accessible. what should I do?

```
      StreamBuilder(
                stream:  FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("app3-e0228-default-rtdb").once().asStream(),

                builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>  snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                     DatabaseEvent databaseEvent = snapshot.data!; //  Get the DatabaseEvent from the AsyncSnapshot
                     var databaseSnapshot = databaseEvent.snapshot; //  Get the DataSnapshot from the DatabaseEvent
                     print('Snapshot: ${databaseSnapshot.value}');
                    return Text("${databaseSnapshot.value}");
                  } else {
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                }),
```

**DataBase**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The first problem I spot is here:

```
stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .ref("app3-e0228-default-rtdb")
    .once()
    .asStream(),
```

You're calling `once()`, which means you read the value from the database once (hence its name), and then turn that into a stream. So your stream will just have one element.

If you want to listen to the database and receive updates too, use `onValue`:

```
stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .ref("app3-e0228-default-rtdb")
    .onValue
```

Inside your `builder` you'll then have a `DataSnapshot` that contains the data from your database, and you can simply do:

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    var databaseEvent = snapshot.data!; //  Get the DatabaseEvent from the AsyncSnapshot
    var databaseSnapshot = databaseEvent.snapshot; //  Get the DataSnapshot from the DatabaseEvent
    print('Snapshot: ${databaseSnapshot.value}');
    return LiveMatch();
  } else {
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
```

Comment: and stream is also not working ..like FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .ref("app3-e0228-default-rtdb")
    .onValue             and if i use as above then values are shown but didn't updated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you implemented streamSubscription and tried listening to it?
StreamBuilder will automatically update data whenever there are changes made.

Comment: How can i subscribe stream in above code?

Comment: Check this out: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-stream-basics-for-beginners-eda23e44e32f

Comment: I read this artical before this, but i am unable to understand that how can use this with my firebase databaseevent?  @Ujjawal Maurya

Comment: You can find how to use StreamBuilder correctly easily anywhere.